# Virgo 3.7.2 deployment issues

Tags: eclipse-virgo

I'm trying to start migrating to Eclipse Virgo 3.7.2 to move to Spring 4.3.9.
I'm getting a stream of Uses violation errors that we didn't have before with 3.6.4. I had to make some adjustments to migrate the spring schemas and remove the springframework libd which seems to be gone now but nothing to explain the following:

```
     fs-watcher                   <DE0002E> Installation of plan 'multi-artifact.plan' version '1.0.0' failed. org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.osgi.framework.UnableToSatisfyBundleDependenciesException: Unable to satisfy dependencies of bundle 'multi-artifact.plan-1-org.geppetto.frontend' at version '0.3.9': Cannot resolve: multi-artifact.plan-1-org.geppetto.frontend
        Resolver report:
            An Import-Package could not be resolved. Resolver error data <Import-Package: org.springframework.web.servlet; version="0.0.0">. Caused by missing constraint in bundle <multi-artifact.plan-1-org.geppetto.frontend_0.3.9>
                 constraint: <Import-Package: org.springframework.web.servlet; version="0.0.0">
            An Import-Package could not be resolved. Resolver error data <Import-Package: org.geppetto.frontend.admin; version="0.0.0">. Caused by missing constraint in bundle <multi-artifact.plan-1-synthetic.context_1.0.0>
                 constraint: <Import-Package: org.geppetto.frontend.admin; version="0.0.0"> constrained to bundle <multi-artifact.plan-1-org.geppetto.frontend> constrained bundle version range "[0.3.9,0.3.9]"
                with attributes {module_scope=multi-artifact.plan-1}

        Uses violation: <Import-Package: org.springframework.http.converter.xml; version="[4.3.9.RELEASE,4.3.9.RELEASE]"> in bundle <org.springframework.webmvc_4.3.9.RELEASE[1532366399144]>
             Resolver reported uses conflict for import

    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.resolve.internal.QuasiResolveStage.process(QuasiResolveStage.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.StandardPipeline.doProcessGraph(StandardPipeline.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.CompensatingPipeline.doProcessGraph(CompensatingPipeline.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.AbstractPipelineStage.process(AbstractPipelineStage.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.StandardPipeline.doProcessGraph(StandardPipeline.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.AbstractPipelineStage.process(AbstractPipelineStage.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.driveInstallPipeline(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.doInstall(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.install(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.deploy(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.hot.HotDeploymentFileSystemListener.deploy(HotDeployerFileSystemListener.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.hot.HotDeploymentFileSystemListener.deployIfNotDeployed(HotDeployerFileSystemListener.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.hot.HotDeploymentFileSystemListener.onChange(HotDeployerFileSystemListener.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.util.io.FileSystemChecker.notifyListeners(FileSystemChecker.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.util.io.FileSystemChecker.check(FileSystemChecker.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.hot.WatchTask.run(WatchTask.java:49)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

[2018-07-23 19:20:12.041] fs-watcher                   <DE0003E> Install failed for bundle 'multi-artifact.plan-1-org.geppetto.model' version '0.3.9'. 
[2018-07-23 19:20:12.042] fs-watcher                   <DE0003E> Install failed for bundle 'multi-artifact.plan-1-org.geppetto.core' version '0.3.9'. 
[2018-07-23 19:20:12.043] fs-watcher                   <DE0003E> Install failed for bundle 'multi-artifact.plan-1-org.geppetto.model.neuroml' version '0.3.9'. 
[2018-07-23 19:20:12.044] fs-watcher                   <DE0003E> Install failed for bundle 'multi-artifact.plan-1-org.geppetto.simulation' version '0.3.9'. 
[2018-07-23 19:20:12.046] fs-watcher                   <DE0003E> Install failed for bundle 'multi-artifact.plan-1-org.geppetto.frontend' version '0.3.9'. 
[2018-07-23 19:20:12.047] fs-watcher                   <DE0003E> Install failed for plan 'multi-artifact.plan' version '1.0.0'. 
[2018-07-23 19:20:12.048] fs-watcher                   <DE0500E> Unable to install application from URI 'file:/home/walrus/code/virgo-tomcat-server-3.7.2.RELEASE/pickup/geppetto.plan'. Cannot satisfy constraints for bundle 'multi-artifact.plan-1-org.geppetto.frontend' version '0.3.9'. Cannot resolve: multi-artifact.plan-1-org.geppetto.frontend
    Resolver report:
        An Import-Package could not be resolved. Resolver error data <Import-Package: org.springframework.web.servlet; version="0.0.0">. Caused by missing constraint in bundle <multi-artifact.plan-1-org.geppetto.frontend_0.3.9>
             constraint: <Import-Package: org.springframework.web.servlet; version="0.0.0">
        An Import-Package could not be resolved. Resolver error data <Import-Package: org.geppetto.frontend.admin; version="0.0.0">. Caused by missing constraint in bundle <multi-artifact.plan-1-synthetic.context_1.0.0>
             constraint: <Import-Package: org.geppetto.frontend.admin; version="0.0.0"> constrained to bundle <multi-artifact.plan-1-org.geppetto.frontend> constrained bundle version range "[0.3.9,0.3.9]"
            with attributes {module_scope=multi-artifact.plan-1}

        Uses violation: <Import-Package: org.springframework.http.converter.xml; version="[4.3.9.RELEASE,4.3.9.RELEASE]"> in bundle <org.springframework.webmvc_4.3.9.RELEASE[1532366399144]>
             Resolver reported uses conflict for import
. org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.osgi.framework.UnableToSatisfyBundleDependenciesException: Unable to satisfy dependencies of bundle 'multi-artifact.plan-1-org.geppetto.frontend' at version '0.3.9': Cannot resolve: multi-artifact.plan-1-org.geppetto.frontend
    Resolver report:
        An Import-Package could not be resolved. Resolver error data <Import-Package: org.springframework.web.servlet; version="0.0.0">. Caused by missing constraint in bundle <multi-artifact.plan-1-org.geppetto.frontend_0.3.9>
             constraint: <Import-Package: org.springframework.web.servlet; version="0.0.0">
        An Import-Package could not be resolved. Resolver error data <Import-Package: org.geppetto.frontend.admin; version="0.0.0">. Caused by missing constraint in bundle <multi-artifact.plan-1-synthetic.context_1.0.0>
             constraint: <Import-Package: org.geppetto.frontend.admin; version="0.0.0"> constrained to bundle <multi-artifact.plan-1-org.geppetto.frontend> constrained bundle version range "[0.3.9,0.3.9]"
            with attributes {module_scope=multi-artifact.plan-1}

        Uses violation: <Import-Package: org.springframework.http.converter.xml; version="[4.3.9.RELEASE,4.3.9.RELEASE]"> in bundle <org.springframework.webmvc_4.3.9.RELEASE[1532366399144]>
             Resolver reported uses conflict for import

    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.resolve.internal.QuasiResolveStage.process(QuasiResolveStage.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.StandardPipeline.doProcessGraph(StandardPipeline.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.CompensatingPipeline.doProcessGraph(CompensatingPipeline.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.AbstractPipelineStage.process(AbstractPipelineStage.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.StandardPipeline.doProcessGraph(StandardPipeline.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.AbstractPipelineStage.process(AbstractPipelineStage.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.driveInstallPipeline(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.doInstall(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.install(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.deploy(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.hot.HotDeploymentFileSystemListener.deploy(HotDeployerFileSystemListener.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.hot.HotDeploymentFileSystemListener.deployIfNotDeployed(HotDeployerFileSystemListener.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.hot.HotDeploymentFileSystemListener.onChange(HotDeployerFileSystemListener.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.util.io.FileSystemChecker.notifyListeners(FileSystemChecker.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.util.io.FileSystemChecker.check(FileSystemChecker.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.hot.WatchTask.run(WatchTask.java:49)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

[2018-07-23 19:20:12.053] fs-watcher                   <HD0002E> Hot deploy failed for file 'geppetto.plan'. org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.api.core.DeploymentException: Dependency satisfaction failed
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.driveInstallPipeline(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.doInstall(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.install(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.deploy(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.hot.HotDeploymentFileSystemListener.deploy(HotDeployerFileSystemListener.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.hot.HotDeploymentFileSystemListener.deployIfNotDeployed(HotDeployerFileSystemListener.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.hot.HotDeploymentFileSystemListener.onChange(HotDeployerFileSystemListener.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.util.io.FileSystemChecker.notifyListeners(FileSystemChecker.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.util.io.FileSystemChecker.check(FileSystemChecker.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.hot.WatchTask.run(WatchTask.java:49)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.osgi.framework.UnableToSatisfyBundleDependenciesException: Unable to satisfy dependencies of bundle 'multi-artifact.plan-1-org.geppetto.frontend' at version '0.3.9': Cannot resolve: multi-artifact.plan-1-org.geppetto.frontend
    Resolver report:
        An Import-Package could not be resolved. Resolver error data <Import-Package: org.springframework.web.servlet; version="0.0.0">. Caused by missing constraint in bundle <multi-artifact.plan-1-org.geppetto.frontend_0.3.9>
             constraint: <Import-Package: org.springframework.web.servlet; version="0.0.0">
        An Import-Package could not be resolved. Resolver error data <Import-Package: org.geppetto.frontend.admin; version="0.0.0">. Caused by missing constraint in bundle <multi-artifact.plan-1-synthetic.context_1.0.0>
             constraint: <Import-Package: org.geppetto.frontend.admin; version="0.0.0"> constrained to bundle <multi-artifact.plan-1-org.geppetto.frontend> constrained bundle version range "[0.3.9,0.3.9]"
            with attributes {module_scope=multi-artifact.plan-1}

        Uses violation: <Import-Package: org.springframework.http.converter.xml; version="[4.3.9.RELEASE,4.3.9.RELEASE]"> in bundle <org.springframework.webmvc_4.3.9.RELEASE[1532366399144]>
             Resolver reported uses conflict for import

    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.resolve.internal.QuasiResolveStage.process(QuasiResolveStage.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.StandardPipeline.doProcessGraph(StandardPipeline.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.CompensatingPipeline.doProcessGraph(CompensatingPipeline.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.AbstractPipelineStage.process(AbstractPipelineStage.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.StandardPipeline.doProcessGraph(StandardPipeline.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.AbstractPipelineStage.process(AbstractPipelineStage.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.driveInstallPipeline(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:359)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Our project is maven based, and in the pom.xml file we are using the following dependencies:

```
enter code here

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
```

Where the spring.version = 4.3.9

Virgo 3.7.2 also comes with springframework 4.3.9 dependencies in repository/ext folder.

The pickpup plan I'm using looks like this: 
[pick up plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j0N7.png)

The artifact that's causing the problem is the last one, org.geppetto.frontend. If I remove it from the plan, and then go to http://localhost:8080/admin/content/artifacts and manually deploy the artifact from there, I don't get the error.

Any ideas on what's going on are much appreciated !

Comment: Hi,

to reproduce your issue I followed the instructions http://docs.geppetto.org/en/latest/osxlinuxsetup.html to build Geppetto and imported the code into an IDE.

I bumped the Spring Framework version to 4.3.9 and Tomcat to 8.5.16, but wasn't able to compile the code due to compile errors in org.geppetto.frontend.messaging.DefaultMessageSenderFactory. Some classes have been removed in Tomcat 8 and "Replaced by the JSR356 WebSocket 1.1 implementation".

Comment: Thanks for testing ! We did the migration already, but it's on another branch not yet on master/development https://github.com/openworm/org.geppetto.frontend/tree/update-virgo-test .
In that branch the outdated spring-osgi dependencies have already been replaced, at least the ones we were aware of. The errors can only be seen when running virgo through the console using the default "startup.sh" file. In Eclipse IDE I can start virgo with the same bundles and it works.